# Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed but i dont see anything wrong with my code

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I have been having this problem for the past week, I have searched everywhere but wasn't able to find a problem.

My service

```js
private texst!: Posts[];

  
  public getPosts(): Observable<Posts[]>
  { 

    return this.http.get<Posts[]>("http://localhost/projects/php_rest_api/api/post/read.php").pipe(map((data) => {
      return this.texst = data;
    }));
  }
```

My Component, here i add the service and run the function to get the data from my database

```js
public test: Posts[] = [];]

  constructor(public postService: PostsService,
              private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPosts();
  }

  public getPosts()
  {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe((response) => {
      this.test = response;
      console.log(this.test);
    })
  }
```

My html

```html
<div>
    <button (click)="getPosts()"></button>
    <div *ngFor="let test of test">
        {{test.title}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: use a different name for the iterator? you're using test twice.

Comment: it's only `return this.http.get<Posts[]>("http://localhost/projects/php_rest_api/api/post/read.php")` without map. You're "mapping" to nothing. Are you trying to map to a property of the response? `.pipe(map(res=>res.property))` or `.pipe(map(res=>{return res.property}))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it

changed the response to object.values in my getPosts() function

```
 public getPosts()
  {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe((response) => {
      this.test = Object.values(response);
      console.log(this.test);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this, rename your var `test` to `testItem` because it's already used:

```
<div>
    <button (click)="getPosts()"></button>
    <div *ngFor="let testItem of test">
        {{testItem.title}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried that, same result

Answer (score 1):

It means you're trying to iterate over object, but you think it's an array.

If that image is a log of the `response`, you better do:

```
public getPosts()
  {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe((response) => {
      this.test = response.data; // <.. this changes!
    })
  }
```

and in template:

```
<div *ngFor="let testItem of test">
      {{testItem.title}}
</div>
```

Comment: tried that, it says "Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Posts[]'".